# How to play IMFMediaEngine background audio while SpeechSynthesizer is playing

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, speech-synthesis

I want to play Windows Phone 8's Speech Synthesizer while background audio is playing. But every time, I activate the Speech Synthesizer, the background audio stops playing, and resumes after the synthesizer finishes.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Some code snippets below:
Background Audio: using IMFMediaEngine in C++, plays successfully.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMFMediaEngine> m_mediaEngine;
m_mediaEngine->Play();
```

In C# / XAML, I have a XAML page with a button, when I click on it, it plays from WP8's latest Speech classes. Plays the text.

```
using Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis; 


public async void SpeakText(string text)
{
    SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    await speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
}
```

I tried putting the SpeakTextAsync through threads, but I guess I'm doing it all wrong, because I still can't get both audio playing at the same time.

```
    private void bubble_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       App.Manager.SpeakText("hello how are you");

// TRY 1: plays text only, background doesn't play
       //new Thread(() =>
       //{
       //    App.Manager.SpeakText(chinese);
       //}).Start();

// TRY 2: plays text only, background doesn't play
       //Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
       //{
       //    App.Manager.SpeakText(chinese);
       //});

// TRY 3: plays text only, background doesn't play
       //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SpeakTextProc));

   }

   private void SpeakTextProc(Object stateInfo)
   {
      App.Manager.SpeakText("Hello how are you");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone 7, I was able to get two separate audio streams using XNA but seeing how that XNA isn't supported for further development on Windows Phone 8, that's not a great solution for you good luck.

Comment: Just because it won't be supported doesn't mean you can't use it for now. XNA is still included in Windows Phone 8 for backwards compatibility. And it is the only way I know of to play sound effects without killing background music.